# Can't call to HANA stored procedure which has Table Type Input Parameter through .Net application

Tags: c#, .net, database, stored-procedures, hana

How can I set input parameter type as `Table Type` Parameter in **HANA** stored procedure when calling from a .Net application ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you cannot directly hand over a table typed parameter from a SAP HANA client. As a workaround you can consider creating a fitting temp table, fill it from your client and call the procedure with a reference to the temp table.

Alternatively, you may consider using a wrapper procedure to call from your client and set up the table typed parameter in SQLScript.